# Looking for an R function to detect a duplicate or the same value in a tibble

Tags: r, function, tibble

I have a tibble :

```
athletes <-athletes %>%
            clean_names() %>% 
            rename(atheletes_id = id)

athletes_with_mutli_country <- country %>%
  select(athlete_id, NOC) %>%
  unique()
```

with these data:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12OOT.png)

etc.

I would like to detect when an athelete_id is there more than once.
How would be the simplest what to do that?

Best,
Stephen

Comment: `country %>%
  group_by(athlete_id) %>%
  mutate(nb_id = n(), duplicated_id = ifelse(nb_id > 1, 'dup', 'no_dup'))`

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by simple. Davids answer covers how to do it in base R. If you want simple as in lines of code, you can use the `janitor` package.

```
if(!require("janitor")){
    install.packages("janitor")
}

# returns the df with a new column "dupe_count" which shows number of entries with same column(s):

athletes %>% 
    janitor::get_dupes(atheletes_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(x  = c(1:5, 5:10),
       y = LETTERS[1:11]) %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  mutate(count = n())
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help to clarify the question if you could show your expected output. I'm assuming that you want to remove duplicate athlete_ids from your data frame.

In Base R there is a function `duplicated` that can find duplicate values in a vector. You can use that plus the subsetting operators to remove the duplicate athletes from your data frame.  Here is an example:

```
# Create sample data
athletes <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '
athlete_id  NOC
183         UAR
184         EGY
185         EGY
186         UAR
187         EGY
188         EGY
189         SUD
184         EGY
191         EGY
192         EGY
193         UAR
183         UAR
195         EGY')

# Detect duplicates
dupes <- duplicated(athletes$athlete_id)

# Remove duplicates
athletes[!dupes, ]
#    athlete_id NOC
# 1         183 UAR
# 2         184 EGY
# 3         185 EGY
# 4         186 UAR
# 5         187 EGY
# 6         188 EGY
# 7         189 SUD
# 9         191 EGY
# 10        192 EGY
# 11        193 UAR
# 13        195 EGY
```